# How to fix Value Error using NLTK array in Python?

Tags: python, nltk

I am getting the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "X:\Learning\Learning.py", line 46, in 
training = np.array(training)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions. The detected shape was (26, 2) + inhomogeneous part.

on this code

```
import random
import json
import pickle
import numpy as np
import nltk
import tensorflow
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from tensorflow.python.types.doc_typealias import document

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
intents = json.loads(open("X:/Memory/intents.json").read())
words = []
classes = []
documents = []
ignore_letters = ["!", "?", ".", ","]
for intent in intents['intents']:
    for pattern in intent['patterns']:
        word_list = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
        words.extend(word_list)
        documents.append((word_list, intent['tag']))
        if intent['tag'] not in classes:
            classes.append(intent['tag'])

words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in words if word not in ignore_letters]
words = sorted(set(words))
pickle.dump(words, open('words.pkl', 'wb'))
pickle.dump(words, open('classes.pkl', 'wb'))

training = []
output_empty = [0] * len(classes)
for document in documents:
    bag = []
    word_patterns = document[0]
    word_patterns = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word.lower()) for word in word_patterns]
    for word in words:
        bag.append(1) if word in word_patterns else bag.append(0)

    output_row = list(output_empty)
    output_row[classes.index(document[1])] = 1
    training.append([bag, output_row])

random.shuffle(training)
training = np.array(training)

train_x = list(training[:, 0])
train_y = list(training[:, 1])

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, input_shape=(len(train_x[0]),), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(len(train_y[0]), activation='softmax'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(np.array[train_x], np.array(train_y), epochs=200, batch_size=5, verbose=1)
model.save('X:/Memory/ModelLearning.mem')
```

I'm expecting a result to come back with no errors.
I'm new to Python and using this tutorial: [Intelligent AI Chatbot in Python](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1lwddP0KUEg) to code a AI bot

Answer (score 0):

Fix it, I changed one line slightly by adding the following:

```
training = np.array(training, dtype=object)
```